# Elasticsearch How to add bool query inside must_not with multiple match in java API?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a query like this in Elasticsearch:

```
{
    "query": { 
        "bool": { 
          "must_not": [
            { "match": "filed1" : "value1"},
            { "match": "filed2" : "value2"}
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

I have tried below code.but it only for single match.

> BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
>   boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field1","value1");

What is the way to use `must_not` with `multiple match` in java API.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start! You can simply call `mustNot()` as many times as conditions you need:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery(); 
boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field1","value1"));
boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field2","value2"));
```

Simple as that ;-)

Comment: Thanks.It works.But what if i have to use only one mustNot with multiple match in bool query.

Comment: You mean multiple match in `bool/must` ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand, what I gave you above is exactly that, i.e. "multiple match in bool/must_not"

Comment: "what I gave you above is exactly that".Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a bit, like the original question was misunderstood. If you have multiple conditions in a single mustNot-constellation, it is not just as easy, as adding multiple .mustNot. Example:

```java
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery(); 
boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","Donald");
boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("hometown","Washington");
```

If You want to exclude all Donalds from Washington, this is not the right solution, because it will exclude ALL Donalds and ALL from Washington.
If you want to combine these two attributes, just create a new Query (think as if you'd code it with brackets...):

```java
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery(); 

BoolQueryBuilder subQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery(); 
subQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","Donald"); // must (positive!)
subQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("hometown","Washington"); // must (positive!)

queryBuilder.mustNot(subQuery); // negate subQuery!
```